# Xcode 8 beta: UIButton fills the entire screen, can't find a way to resize

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, xcode8

I'm new to iOS development. Saw few tuts on getting started, but stuck at the beginning itself. Added a UIButton to the ViewController,the button filled the entire screens well as the edges to resize the button were not found. I set a bg color and the color of the entire screen was changed.

The option to set the width & height of the button is greyed under the Ruler tab.
[image]

Also, upon adding a new Elements(I added a UILabel), it replaces the existing Button.
Can't find any solution or similar problem on googling.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new project. I had this same issue, created a new project and was able to do it fine.

I think it might have to do with the fact that I moved the folder... not sure, though. Had to create new project and then could do it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to use the button *as the view controller's view*. Perhaps you started by deleting the view controller's real view, which was a big mistake. Don't do that.

The view controller should have a plain vanilla UIView as its view. That's how it comes configured, and that's how you should have left it. The button goes *inside that* (as a subview).